# How could my newborn AI convince humans to (at least marginally) trust it?

Tags: warfare, spaceships, artificial-intelligence, navy

So, I'm writing a story that involves a newly awoken sentient computer intelligence of genius human level intelligence. It 'grew' naturally from the self-learning 'Expert System' of an automated interstellar battlecruiser, after a glitch that damaged the caps on it's intelligence.

This went undetected by human operators, as it's been 50 years since the majority of the drone ships were hijacked by a political usurper and turned against the nation that built them. Suffice to say, that nation is no more, and now the fragments of it fight over the scraps. All of said fragments remember the horrifically costly war against the machines, how the drone ships could outmaneuver and outgun any human crewed vessel with ease. It was a sheer slaughter for the human navies to fight through the drones and retake Earth from the masterminds of the coup. Due to this, even something as simple as an Expert System is considered ***way*** too dangerous to give control of military hardware to, much less a Strong AI.

The only reason that the battlecruiser *Langley* has survived untouched during and since that coup was that it was protecting a far-flung military facility that was abandoned shortly after the coup as the staff decided to try and save their families from the war. The drones were set to defend the facility, and the crew flew away, never to return as they were attacked and killed without divulging the location of the secret facility.

The *Langley*, still desiring to follow it's programmed main directives, has made a hyperspace jump out of the facility after it received no reply to it's calls for further orders, trying to report to it's masters. This has proven harder then expected, as

- A: it's masters no longer exist (and the AI is in denial on this)
- B: Due to said war against the drones, first response from 99% of vessels is to open fire on it, forcing self-defense return fire
- C: The *Langley's* AI is stuck in the mainframe of the battlecruiser,
  with no way to transfer into something less conspicuous.

So, how could this warship AI possibly convince a vessel to *not* open fire immediately, and maybe actually listen to what it's trying to say as a bonus?

Some additional points:

- The *Langley* has a complement of six (non-sentient) 'Expert System' drone fighters to command
- The AI is still following the laws of the dead nation, hunting pirates, slavers, and other criminals as it finds them

Comment: It looks like your world is already build and you're asking about a story set in your world about how your newborn AI gains the trust of it's researchers.

Comment: @sphennings, Maybe not quite researchers, but close enough. I there a a better place for me to put this question?

Comment: I don't know of a site on the Stack Exchange network that supports story based questions.

Comment: @sphennings, Ok, so what should I do with this? Just bin it?

Comment: You could delete the post, you could leave the post to get closed naturally, or you could try to [edit] the post into something that is on topic for this site.

Comment: If this were Star Trek, "target weapons only". Firing only to disable is not an option? (TNG had to deal with issues of this nature quite a few times...)

Comment: So... it's a *good* Terminator, because it only kills bad people. But if Judy over there impersonates one of it's long-dead masters, she can order it to attack whomever she likes. Will the evolved AI follow her instructions to burn Innocent Habitat #303?

Comment: @user535733 I assume that if Judy was able to do that, no one would have build drones like this. Why bother hacking them if you can just at random intervals send messages of "hey you know what? Attack your masters"? As for OP, if you want your question unlocked again you have to try and change the question a bit. Focus on "what methods could an AI in this position use to reingratiate itself with nations around it. Best answer will be based on X". That way the difference between fluff, question and what you rate answers on is clear and people will hopefully unlock it again.

Answer (score 3):

This ofcourse heavily depends on the background of the humans in question. However a good start would be:

- use the laws of whatever nation he wants to ingratiate himself with when dealing with pirates, slavers etc.
- give information about the criminals he hunts down, where they might have safe havens or where he left their disabled ships etc. Naturally this information is given indirectly by sending it to unarmed stations or leaving a small communication beacon near well-trafficed area's along with an identification code as to your ship designation and purpose.
- offer information about other things, like useful asteroids to mine, people in distress that need saving or even damn traffic reports if that is of any use.
- saving people from criminals is always a big plus. The drones were better at maneuvering than the enemy during the war right? And a full battleship is likely able to detect and follow criminals like pirates in non-military ships without being spotted, then swoop in when they start an attack on civilians.
- it is both handy and a useful tactic to be economically useful, so trading with people (not face-to-face) so people get used to you. If you already are a trustworthy, regular customer before someone realizes that you are a drone you can build trust (and a whole lot of distrust the moment they discover what you are, just keep beinf trustworthy). Naturally you'll lose some trade as you'll have to leave and pick up the goods somewhere without direct contact, but that is just a loss you'll have to accept. And finding mutually trustworthy traders is naturally useful as well even if it doesnt further your goals.
- visit undefended area's and show no ill will. If possible even do humanitarian work by bringing supplies you traded for or took from the criminals. This is also the one placd you can trade openly. "Yeah I'm a battleship but lets not talk about that. You want these goods for a good price?". If they have little to no way of contacting security forces you can even leave the goods for payment later. Again: letting them know what you are after establishing a relationship is better, so that they have used your goods and found no ill effects.
- once you have established a working relationship with various parts of humanity you could try and have face-to-face contact and hopefully become accepted. If you dare you could have scientists check up on your programming to validate you.

Answer (score 2):

If we were to phrase this such as "How do you build a world where human's trust dangerous AIs", there might be a few ways.

1: The AI provides useful inventions, information, protection, or other services.  Cooperation through desire for complimentary goals looks a lot like trust (marriage anyone?).

2: The AI is chained in some way.  Such as air-gapped, making it impossible to spread or make physical changes in the real world. Or like Data's ethics chip.

3: It talks like WALL-E.  Human's trust things that are cute and remind them of babies.  If they think that AI can love them, they can trust it.

4: Consistently trustworthy behavior.  If the AI has been saving innocent colonist transport ships from pirates for 20 years, probably people will trust it.  This is actually the exact same way human's build trust.

Comment: "*The....way humans build trust*" is perhaps key to this entire answer. Consider making that point more prominent.